# Why in semiconductor studies, we are only concerned with reduced zone representation of e-k diagram?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

Does electron transition from conduction band to valence band takes place only in first Brillouin zone? Or can it happen in any other Brillouin zone?

Answer (score 1):

Electron transistion can happen anywhere in the semiconductor structure.

The first Brillouin zone is defined in the *reciprocal space*. Theoretically, *all* atoms in the original crystal contribute to the "image" in this reciprocal space. So I believe you may have misunderstood what the Brillouin zone represents.

So everything happening in any Brillouin zone theoretically represents the *whole* crystal.

So it does not really make sense to say "transition outside the Brillouin zone". The *whole* crystal is mapped to a cell in the reciprocal space, and a single cell has an effect on *all* cells in the reciprocal space. So if you look at a single electron in the reciprocal space, then the image of that electron is also there in *all* Brillouin zones.

Comment: I am actually saying that transition occurs around k=0 in an ek diagram .

Comment: Can electron jump from say k=2pi/a to k=0??

Comment: The Brillouin zone is the whole cell, not just around k=0. But yes, electron transition can happen anywhere. I'll edit my post to include more information.

Comment: I edited my post. I believe I only understood your question after you second comment.